# Read values of an (M,N) image from a (2,MN) matrix in python

Tags: python, vectorization

Suppose that I have an (M,N) image J (with shape (M,N,3)). And I have a (2,MN) matrix K like this:

```
0 0 0 ... 0 1 1 1 ... 1 ............. M M M ... M

0 1 2 ... N 1 2 3 ... N ............. 1 2 3 ... N
```

Now I multiply the above matrix by a 2 by 2 matrix to get a new matrix T of the same size as K.

Now I want to create a new image where the pixel (r,s) in this new image is equal to the (R,G,B) value of the pixel of the old image which is in the r*N+M column of T.

I want to do this in a vectorized way if possible. I do not want to use for-loops (I already know how to do this using for-loops, but it's extremely slow). In fact, my interest in this problem is because I want to apply a homography transformation in a vectorized way.

Any help is appreciated. Here's the loopy version for making what I want clear:

```
for r in range(0,M):
    for s in range(0,N):
        x, y = T[:,r*N+s]
        new_image[r,s] = J[x,y]
```

Comment: I'm not very clear with your problem, but I believe numpy mask indices is what you want.

Comment: @KaihongZhang:  Thank you. I googled mask indices and checked the references on numpy's website but couldn't figure how it solved me. Would you please explain how it can help me in this case?

Comment: You can use an array as another array's indices, just like Andras Deak's answer.

Comment: Can't you just use `reshape`, something like `K.reshape(M,N)`?

Comment: @Dan I don't see why that should help. Could you explain please?

Comment: @stressedout nevermind, I misunderstood what you are doing. Are you just applying a transformation matrix (the 2x2) to your image? Why not just use a pre-built function that will do that for you? For example https://www.scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_features.html and it looks like you can pass you 2x2 matrix (padded with 0 because you have no translation) to AffineTransfrom instead of the other parameters in the example: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.AffineTransform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost directly use your index array due to the fortunate layout of the indices inside:

```
import numpy as np

# set up dummy input
M,N = 300,400
J = np.random.rand(M, N, 3)
T = np.array([np.random.randint(0, M, M*N), np.random.randint(0, N, M*N)])

# original    
new_image = np.empty_like(J)
for r in range(0,M):
    for s in range(0,N):
        x, y = T[:,r*N+s]
        new_image[r,s] = J[x,y]

# vectorized new
new_image_vect = J[tuple(T)].reshape(J.shape)
```

Check:

```
>>> np.array_equal(new_image, new_image_vect)
True
```

The way the above works is not entirely trivial, because [advanced indexing is a fickle thing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). What I wrote above is equivalent to

```
J[(T[0,...], T[1,...])].reshape(J.shape) -> J[T[0,...], T[1,...]].reshape(J.shape)
```

Now the first part is clearer: take each element in the first row of `T` and use that as the first index of `J`, then take the corresponding element in the second row of `T` and use that as the corresponding second index of `J`. This part sort of covers `J[x,y]` in the loopy version.

But then since we're essentially indexing the array with 1d arrays of length `M*N`, the shape of the resulting array will also have shape `M*N` along its first dimension (and a trailing dimension of size 3). We thus need to `reshape` the result back to `(M,N,3)`.

All this only works directly because the indices in `T` are stored according to C-contiguous memory order. If this weren't the case we'd have to `transpose` our arrays to and fro in order to generate the resulting array with the right layout.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the last line of your code? (the vectorized way) Why do you use tuple(T) and then reshape it back to its original shape?

Comment: @stressedout please see my update and let me know if it's still unclear

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to first read about advanced indexing before I can understand your answer. But also the last paragraph of your answer is something new for me. Could you tell me where I could read about C-contiguous memory and what it is?

Comment: @stressedout sure. Take your time and let me know once you've read into the subject and still have questions. "C-contiguous" is also known as row-major order, some info [can be found here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html). This means that if you do `np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)` then the numbers increment along the rows. This is row-major order: the data is a contiguous block from 0 to 5, and they are laid out row by row. In contrast, fortran-style or column-major order would contain incremental numbers along columns. This is what MATLAB and fortran use by default.

Comment: I think I don't understand. So, if I use new_image[tuple(T)], the shape of this will be a 1-d array of size M*N*3. Right? So, what if I want new_image to keep its original shape (for example, I initialize it first by using np.zeroes((r,s,t)) before using that command) while only some entries are changed?

Comment: @stressedout `arr[tuple(T)]` is actually the same as `arr[T[0,:], T[1,:], :]` in your 3d case, so it's a 2d array with shape `(M*N, 3)`. If you only want to assign to part of an array, you have to do fancy indexing on the left-hand side as well. For the above copy-everything case you could do `new_image = np.empty_like(J); new_image.reshape(-1,3)[np.arange(T.shape[1])] = J[tuple(T)]`. As you see you don't have to permanently reshape your array to get the indexing right. Of course if you only copy part of the array you'll want to initialize with something like `zeros_like`. Does this help?

Comment: Of course it's probably easier to understand `new_image = np.zeros_like(J).reshape(-1, 3); new_image[np.arange(T.shape[1])] = J[tuple(T)]; new_image = new_image.reshape(J.shape)` in separate reshaping steps.

Comment: I think I need to first improve my knowledge of indexing in numpy and then return to your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @stressedout OK. In the mean time if you need any small-scale help you can find me [in the python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python).

Comment: Thank you. That's nice of you. As a matter of fact, I have asked a new question which has received no acceptable answer yet. I'd appreciate it if you could have a look at it.